# How to delete * character from string and highlight with colour

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I have a String variable (nota) that contains `*` in it. I'm trying to erase these `*` characters between a word (i.e.: `"* human  *"`) and change the word color. But I can't replace or erase `"*"` characters programmatically, something goes wrong.

I've tried `replace` function but without success:

```
if(nota != null) 
    if(nota.contains("*"))
    {
        SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(nota);

        spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), nota.indexOf("*"), 
            nota.indexOf("*") + "*".length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannable = spannable.replace("*","");
        txtnota.setText(spannable);
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `replaceAll` (which would be better as `replace` by the way - you don't need regular expressions) but you're ignoring the return value. Strings are immutable in Java - you can't change their contents, so methods like `replace` return a *new* string.

Comment: @JonSkeet So, how can I fix this? I'm a newbie.

Comment: As I said, use the return value - see the duplicate question, basically.

Comment: @JonSkeet I called `replace` and it continues not working!

Comment: Looking at your code again, I'm not sure how that's compiling at all, as I can't see a `replaceAll` method in `SpannableString`. But you basically want `String noStars = nota.replace("*", "");`

Comment: @JonSkeet how about using `replaceAll` with my `regex` I know it work also.

Comment: @Ironman: Why use a regular expression at all when it's not needed? It's complexity for no benefit.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am givig that idea also see my update answer. Both method work fine.

Comment: @Ironman: Sure, but my point is that that should be the *first* port of call. Avoid regular expressions where possible. Note that the type of `spannable` is `Spannable` rather than `String` though, so I don't know how the OP's code compiles at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check it I have now tested it.

```
 if(nota != null){
      if(nota.contains("*")){

       nota = nota.replace("*","");

       Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(nota);
       spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), nota.indexOf("*"), nota.indexOf("*") + "*".length(),     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       txtnota.setText(spannable);

  }
}
```

Comment: The method replace(String, String) is undefined for the type 
  Spannable

Comment: @HollyIkki see my update answer.

Comment: It continues asking to add cast to 'Spannable' suggestion: spannable = ((String) spannable).replaceAll("\\*","");

Comment: @HollyIkki then add it.

Comment: It didn't work. A red mark under `((String) spannable).replace("\\*",""); ` appears.

Comment: I saw your update answer and I used `SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(nota);` but the red mark persists asking to add cast to 'spannable'

Comment: @HollyIkki I have tested it. see my code.

Comment: Your code is finishing the application :/

Comment: @HollyIkki i update it.

Comment: Sorry! The application is stopped :(